# Why am I losing typing of a parameter with spread operator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, github, octokit

By using a [Octokit](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js) package I'd like to list all pull requests (`client.pulls.list`).

I have a GitHubClient (wrapper for Octokit) and GitHubService (wrapper for GitHubClient).
The GitHubService has an options argument using interface with `perPage?: number;` property, and the GitHubClient accepts options with an interface having property `per_page?: number;`

In my code bellow, I am losing type checking of `options` in GitHubClient class.

What am I doing wrong and how to set the options type correctly?

```js
import Octokit from '@octokit/rest';

interface PaginationParams {
  page?: number;

  // camelcase
  perPage?: number;
}

interface GitHubPaginationParams {
  page?: number;

  // underscored
  per_page?: number;
}

class GitHubClient {
  private client: Octokit;

  constructor() {
    this.client = new Octokit();
  }

  getPullRequests(options: PaginationParams) {
    // lost typings of "options" with spread operator (no typescript error)
    return this.client.pulls.list({ owner: 'octokit', repo: 'hello-world', state: 'open', ...options });

    // this works (typescript error)
    // return this.client.pulls.list({ owner: 'octokit', repo: 'hello-world', state: 'open', page: options.page, per_page: options.per_page });

    // this works
    // return this.client.pulls.list({ owner: 'octokit', repo: 'hello-world', state: 'open', page: options.page, per_page: options.perPage });
  }
}

class GitHubService {
  private ghClient: GitHubClient;

  constructor() {
    this.ghClient = new GitHubClient();
  }

  async getPullRequests(options: GitHubPaginationParams) {
    return this.ghClient.getPullRequests(options);
  }
}
```

I'd expect that typescript throws an error because the `options` interface of GitHubService is different than `options` in GitHubClient interface.

Comment: Just to make sure: have you seen the pagination API for `@octokit/rest`?
https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/#pagination

Comment: @Gregor Yes I have, but we're using Pulls API https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/#octokit-routes-pulls

Answer (score 0):

All your fields (in both interfaces) are optional - that's  mean that even empty object implements those interfaces. Expected behavior will work as soon as you mark fields are required.

Currently you have next:

```
interface PaginationParams {
  page?: number;

  // camelcase
  perPage?: number;
}

interface GitHubPaginationParams {
  page?: number;

  // underscored
  per_page?: number;
}

// cause none of the fields is required
var x:PaginationParams = {};
var y:GitHubPaginationParams = x;
```

if you remove `?` near `page` - types will be compatible by that field. If you remove it for `per_page`/`perPage` - you either get expected error, or you have to provide both properties